# Retrieve only queried element from a single document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a collection like below :

```
`{
    "topics" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "Test1",
            "owner" : [ 
                "123"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "name" : "Test2",
            "owner" : [ 
                "123", 
                "456"
            ]
        }
]
}`
```

As, this data is in single document, and I want only matching elements based on their `owner`, I am using below query ( using filter in aggregation ), but I am getting 0 matching elements.
Query :

Thanks in advance...!!

```
db.getCollection('topics').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"topics.owner":{"$in":["123","456"]}}},
  {"$project":{
    "topics":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$topics",
        "as":"topic",
        "cond": {"$in": ["$$topic.owner",["123","456"]]}
      }},
    "_id":0
  }}
])
```

This query should produce below output :

```
{
    "topics" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Test1",
            "owner" : ["123"]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "Test2",
            "owner" : ["123","456"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `topic.owner` is an array, you can't use `$in` directly as this compares whether the array is within in an array.

Instead, you should do as below:

1. `$filter` - Filter the document in the `topics` array.

   1.1. `$gt` - Compare the result from *1.1.1* is greater than 0.

   1.1.1. `$size` - Get the size of the array from the result *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$setIntersection` - Intersect the `topic.owner` array with the input array.

```
{
  "$project": {
    "topics": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$topics",
        "as": "topic",
        "cond": {
          $gt: [
            {
              $size: {
                $setIntersection: [
                  "$$topic.owner",
                  [
                    "123",
                    "456"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            },
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "_id": 0
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cOLAyLoD4C0)

Comment: Thanks Yong..!! It is working fine in mongo playground, but in actual mongo shell, its giving me one of the error, "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null" I am checking this issue. Thanks again..

Comment: Use `$ifNull` to set default value as empty array. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I4sWiIylkFh)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yong... Well, the query is perfectly working fine in Mongo playground as the Mongo version used is : 6 +, but its failing at my end with the error : "All operands of $setIntersection must be arrays. One argument is of type: string", with Mongo version: 3.4

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, I found the issue with the data, corrected the data and now its working fine and I am getting the desired result. Thanks a lot.. Yong ..!!

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, sorry for late reply. You are welcome. Glad to see my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('topics').aggregate([
{"$unwind":"$topics"},
{"$addFields":{
    "rest":{"$or":[{"$in":["12z3","$topics.owner"]},{"$in":["456","$topics.owner"]}]}
    }},
    {"$match":{
        "rest":true
        }},
        {"$group":{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "topics":{"$push":"$topics"}
            }}
])
```